# Selenium Python - how to send keys to webform

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to fill out a webform using selenium.  Although I am able to successfully populate most text boxes and select radio buttons, I am receiving the below exception when attempting to send keys to the three *[date of birth]* fields (day, month and year) as well as a *[lifecover]* field in the second section of the form.

> ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
>   (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.62)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

The above exception is received from the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

path_to_chromedriver = 'C:/Users/Me/chromedriver/chromedriver'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)

url = 'https://lifeinsurance.rac.com.au/rac/get-a-quote?productid=51'
browser.get(url)

...

# date of birth - CANNOT POPULATE!
browser.find_element_by_id('txtDateOfBirth__1_Day').send_keys('01')
browser.find_element_by_id('txtDateOfBirth__1_Month').send_keys('06')
browser.find_element_by_id('txtDateOfBirth__1_Year').send_keys('1988')

...

# cover amount - CANNOT POPULATE!
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtCoverAmount__1"]').send_keys('150000')

...
```

Complete code (which includes the above) is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

path_to_chromedriver = 'C:/Users/Me/chromedriver/chromedriver'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)

url = 'https://lifeinsurance.rac.com.au/rac/get-a-quote?productid=51'
browser.get(url)

# quote type
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rdApplicantCount_1_Label"]/span[1]').click()

# title
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="divApplicantDetails__1"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/span/span/span[1]').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ddTitle__1_listbox"]/li[2]').click()

# first name and surname
browser.find_element_by_name('txtFirstName__1').send_keys('richard')
browser.find_element_by_name('txtSurname__1').send_keys('castle')

# email
browser.find_element_by_name('txtEmail__1').send_keys('rcastle@gmail.com')

# mobile number
browser.find_element_by_name('txtPhoneNumber__1').send_keys('0418545898')

# date of birth - CANNOT POPULATE!
browser.find_element_by_id('txtDateOfBirth__1_Day').send_keys('01')
browser.find_element_by_id('txtDateOfBirth__1_Month').send_keys('06')
browser.find_element_by_id('txtDateOfBirth__1_Year').send_keys('1988')

# gender
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rdGender_Female__1_Label"]/span[1]').click()

# residence
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="divApplicantDetails__1"]/div[8]/div/div[2]/span/span/span[1]').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ddResidentialStatusId__1_listbox"]/li[1]').click()

# residing in australia
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rdResidingInAustralia_Yes__1_Label"]/span[1]').click()

# open cover section
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="divQuote_Accordion"]/div[3]/div').click()

# tobacco
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rdSmoker_Yes__1_Label"]/span[1]').click()

# cover amount - CANNOT POPULATE!
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtCoverAmount__1"]').send_keys('150000')

# get quote
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="divApplicantCover"]/div[3]/div[2]/button').click()

# premium frequency
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="productTabStrip-1"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[2]/span/span/span[1]').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ddPremiumFrequencyId_listbox"]/li[2]').click()

# capture result
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="productTabStrip-1"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/span').text
```

I am new to selenium and would appreciate if someone could advise how to send keys to the fields raising exceptions

Comment: You should try with explicit wait on the visibility on these input fields. http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check HTML source of `input` field, you'll see that it has `style="display: none;"` attribute, which means that you cannot interact with this element even if to implement Explicit/Implicit wait... To make it visible, try to change `style="display: none;"` to `style="display: inline;"` as below:

```
day = browser.find_element_by_id('txtDateOfBirth__1_Day')
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].style.display="inline";', day)
day.send_keys('01')
```

Perform the same for two other input fields

Answer (score 1):

You can use Selenium [waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

In your case, I would use an **Implicit wait**:

> An implicit wait tells WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find any element (or elements) not immediately available. The default setting is 0. Once set, the implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object.

E.g.:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

path_to_chromedriver = 'C:/Users/Me/chromedriver/chromedriver'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)
browser.implicitly_wait(10) # Here you set it

url = 'https://lifeinsurance.rac.com.au/rac/get-a-quote?productid=51'
browser.get(url)
...
```